# CSS percentual padding / margin in border-box

Tags: css, padding, percentage

To my understanding, using `box-sizing:content-box`, when setting the padding and margin of an element in percent, these will be the percent of the width of the actual content area. So a 50% margin of a 300px wide image, without any relation to its padding, will create a 150px wide margin and therefore an actual size of 450px width (+padding).

Now, when I use `box-sizing:border-box`, width is defined as content+padding+border. If I set the padding of my element in border-box using percent, will it refer to this different definition of width, therefore referring to itself? If not, and it refers to the content's width only, in that case the content width itself is also dependent of the padding's and border's width (content width=(border-box width)-border-padding), therefore a higher percentage on the padding would refer to a smaller content, making the padding itself smaller again. Am I understanding this right? This seems like the padding would base itself off itself to me in both cases. What am I missing? And in what order is the browser calculating the percentages, based on what (the content only or the actual width)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html

Comment: **vertical** and horizontal  margins or padding uses parent's width for reference (pseudo will use their related container if BFC is created). box-sizing won't matter  https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties , https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties and some infos about box-sizing that you might want to read https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-box-20021024/#the-box-width

Comment: So if I make an image smaller using content-box, it will enlarge both padding and margin. And if I do the same using border-box, it will make the padding smalle together with the image and the margin gets larger? 
Also thanks to both of you. The fact that margin and padding are using percent of the parent element and not of the element itself clears it all up. My sources were not precise on that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what you set `box-sizing` to with respect to how the actual sizes of margins and borders are calculated. It will be the same either way.

What `content-box` or `border-box` do is control with width and height of an element so that the border and padding are not included (`content-box`) or they are included (`border-box`) in the overall size specified by `height` and `width`.

Also, borders can't have a width set to a percentage and padding is based on the element's width, not content.

```css
#one {
  box-sizing:content-box; /* default */
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  padding:10%; /* padding % is a percentage of the element's width */
  border:1px solid red;
  border:10% solid black;  /* Borders can't be set to percentages */
  background:yellow;
  float:left;
}

#two {
  box-sizing:border-box; /* default */
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  padding:10%; /* padding % is a percentage of the element's width */
  border:1px solid red;
  border:10% solid black;  /* Borders can't be set to percentages */
  background:blue;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the phrase " /* padding % is a percentage of the element's width */"  only applies, because you set width:100%, right? As stated in the answers above, padding and margin should be relative to the parent element's width. So a smaller width on #one or #two shouldn't change the padding of both?